# How to do callback in jquery, when getting attr href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have this code:

```
$("#downloadPopup").attr("href")
```

Which give me back a link, but i want to have a callback to make the link is been gathered, for instance:

```
  $("#downloadPopup").attr("href", function(){
        console.log($(this)); 
       // i need make sure the link value is available (promise).
    });
```

I tried this but it does not work, im not sure if i have to pass paramaters to the callback. thanks

Comment: `if ( $("#downloadPopup").attr("href") != "" )` ????

Comment: Do you want to track when it changes? or just get the current value. If you just want the current value, you don't need a callback.

Comment: why don't you just use '$("#downloadPopup").attr("href")' as the parameter for console.log()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done quite simply like so

```
// Here we save a reference to the orginal method
$.fn._attr = $.fn.attr;

// We can now define our own version
$.fn.attr = function ( attr, callback ) {

    // Now we test to make sure that the arguments are provided in the way you want
    if ( typeof attr === 'string' && typeof callback === 'function' ) {

        // Save the result of the callback
        var result = callback.call( this, attr );

        // If the callback returns a valid "value" we assign that as the new attribute
        if ( typeof result === 'string' ) {
            return $.fn._attr( attr, result );
        }

    }

    // If the arguments, or return of our function, are not what we expected, we execute the normal method here
    return $.fn._attr.apply( this, arguments );

};
```

To use this new `attr` function we can do this

```
// Here prop is the name of the attribute you passed in
$( 'div' ).attr( 'foo', function ( prop ) {
    return prop + 'bar';
});
```

The result of this would be

```
<div foo="foobar"></div>
```

Comment: But, why do it this way?

Comment: @jfriend00 - just rewriting jQuery for no apparent reason is always a good idea, and it's fun as well !

Comment: Wait... doesn't .attr already support this syntax?

Comment: I love this answer. I don't think this is what the OP wants/needs, but it certainly answers the question he asked. Nicely done. +1

Comment: The OP is asking to add functionality to a method? This does that. How is this no reason?

Comment: .attr already accepts a 2nd argument that is a function, how does your modified method take that into account? as it stands now, it completely replaces that functionality (which already does what your "new" way of doing it does)

Comment: Reference: http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr

Comment: It allows for a point of entry if he wants to do further testing before passing it to the jQuery version. The OP has since edited his question from when I answered

Comment: @KevinB - Well, this returns the name of the attribute and lets you add the name to the value, which jQuery's function parameter does'nt, for obvious reasons, as there's really no point ?

Comment: @KevinB Contrary to what the docs say, I just checked the source of version 1.3.2 and it does not look like it supports passing a function, even though the docs say it supported it since 1.0. Maybe that's why the OP asked this question?

Comment: It's supported since 1.1, here's a fiddle of 1.3.2 http://jsfiddle.net/KN6FG/ and 1.1 http://jsfiddle.net/KN6FG/1/

Answer (score 6):

Getting the value of an attribute is not an asynchronous operation, since the information is in the DOM you can just get it. You don't need to use a callback.

```
var pop = $("#downloadPopup")
var href = pop.attr("href");
doSomethingWith(pop, href);
```

You need to use a callback when you can't perform the operation immediately. e.g. when an HTTP request gets a response, when a link is clicked by the user or when a `setTimeout` reaches 0.